# launch is only available since Kotlin 1.3 and cannot be used in Kotlin 1.2

Tags: kotlin, coroutine

Пытаюсь запустить [простейший пример с корутинами](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/core/kotlinx-coroutines-core/test/guide/example-basic-01.kt):

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        delay(1000L)
        println("${Thread.currentThread().name}: World")
    }
    println("${Thread.currentThread().name}: Hello")
    Thread.sleep(2000L)
    println("${Thread.currentThread().name}: Finish!")
}
```

*build.gradle* файл выглядит следующим образом:

```
buildscript {
    // Consider moving these values to `gradle.properties`
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.0-rc-146'
    ext.kotlin_gradle_plugin_version = '1.3.0-rc-198'
    ext.kotlinx_coroutines = '1.0.0-RC1'

    repositories {
        maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlin-eap" }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.51"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version "1.1.51"
}

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'application'
group 'by.kotlin'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

mainClassName = 'MainKt'

repositories {
    maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlin-eap" }
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    google()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlinx_coroutines"   
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

И при запуске получаю следующие ошибки:

```
e: ...Main.kt: (6, 17): 'launch(CoroutineContext = ..., CoroutineStart = ..., [ERROR : Bad suspend function in metadata with constructor: Function2]<CoroutineScope, Continuation<Unit>, Any?>): Job' is only available since Kotlin 1.3 and cannot be used in Kotlin 1.2
e: ...Main.kt: (7, 9): Suspend function 'delay' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function
e: ...Main.kt: (7, 9): 'delay(Long): Unit' is only available since Kotlin 1.3 and cannot be used in Kotlin 1.2
> Task :compileKotlin FAILED
```

В чём причина этой ошибки?

Настройки IntelliJ IDEA:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как запускаете-то? Очень похоже что среда исполнения у вас 1.2.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, да, кажется, Вы правы (добавила скрин настроек IDE). Но в выпадающем списке Language version максимальная версия, которую можно выбрать, - это 1.2... Как можно это изменить?

Comment: В итоге Kotlin я обновила, пример запустился, но IntelliJ IDEA всё равно подчёркивает красным launch и delay.

Comment: Плагин Котлина обновите, он все еще у вас 1.2